# normal subgroups of $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $S_3$ be the set of all permutation of $\{1,2,3\}$.
Let $\delta , \tau \in S_3$ be $\delta(1)=(2),\delta(2)=3,\delta(3)=1$ and $\tau(1)=2,\tau(2)=1,\tau(3)=3$.

Are $\langle\delta\rangle,\langle\tau\rangle$ normal? where $\langle\delta\rangle=\{\delta^n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ and $\langle\tau\rangle=\{\tau^n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$

I **guess** $\langle\delta\rangle$ is normal but $\langle\tau\rangle$ is not.

It is obvious that $\langle\delta\rangle=\{1,\delta,\delta^{-1} \}$ where 1 is the identity mapping. but how can i prove this?

After proving this, if i can prove $s \delta s^{-1} \in \langle\delta\rangle$ for any $s \in S_3$, then $s \delta^{-1} s=(s \delta s^{-1})(s \delta s^{-1}) \in \langle\delta\rangle$ and $s1s^{-1}=1 \in \langle\delta\rangle$. So $s\langle\delta\rangle s^{-1} \subseteq \langle\delta\rangle$ hence $\langle\delta\rangle$ is normal.

but $s$ is any element of $S_3$, how can i calculate $s \delta s^{-1}$ so that i can show $s \delta s^{-1} \in \langle\delta\rangle$?

Moreover, is $\langle\tau\rangle$ normal? i can't really see the answer.

Comment: $\langle \delta \rangle$ is a subgroup of index 2, and so it is normal. $\langle \tau \rangle$ is not normal, as you could see by computing $\delta \tau \delta^{-1}$. You can do these computations just by drawing diagrams!

Answer (score 2):

In full symmetric groups, you should use the fact that for a $k$-cycle:

$\rho = (a_1\ a_2\ \cdots\ a_k)$, and any $\sigma \in S_n$ (where, of course, $k \leq n$)

$\sigma\rho\sigma^{-1}$ is the $k$-cycle $(\sigma(a_1)\ \sigma(a_2)\ \cdots\ \sigma(a_k))$.

In particular, we can conjugate any transposition (or $k$-cycle, for that matter), to obtain any other transposition (or $k$-cycle). So, for any subgroup to be normal, it must at *least* contain every $k$-cycle, for every $k$-cycle it contains.

Several proofs of this fact are on this site, I urge you to search for them.

Another useful fact (as concerns your permutation $\delta$, which generates a subgroup of index two) is that any subgroup of a group which has index $2$ is necessarily normal (why?).

Comment: You are saying there is one conjugacy class of $S_n$ for each partition of $n$  (ie. the class of $(abc)(de)(f)(g)$ is $1+1+2+3$)

Comment: *Ordered* partitions, that is-for example, for $n = 3$, we regard $1+2$ as the same partition as $2+1$ (this is because disjoint cycles commute).

Comment: Yes so unordered partitiions